# Running LibGDX app

Tags: libgdx, lag

Sometimes, when I launch my game in LibGDX (the game doesn't require much power) the rendering is very laggy, but most of the time, when I run it the game runs smooth perfectly.

I would understand this if it would be laggy all the time, but it's laggy only in about 10% of the times when I run it. When I close it and run it again, it runs perfectly. Why is this happening?

I use Eclipse for launching and it runs as a desktop app.

Comment: Does the lag stay, or does the lag eventually go away, meaning it only happens when you first open the app?

Comment: It stays laggy. It shows me about 45 fps and normally it runs 60.

Comment: Is this happening in an emulator, or actual Android device? If so, what version of Android?

Comment: I should have mentioned that, it's desktop app.

Comment: So this isn't happening on Android, but rather, just the Desktop Java version? I'm more inclined to argue that you must have a bug going on in your code. A desktop machine should have no problem getting 60FPS. Can you post your code that is doing the delay of each frame?

Comment: It's not Android app, It's only meant for desktop.

Comment: I edited my question above. Can you provide your code for the frame delay?

Comment: 90% of the times I run it, it gets to 60 fps (and sometimes even above) but sometimes (in the 10%) it starts to lag.

Comment: No one can do anything if you don't provide code.

Comment: Run your app with verbose garbage collection logs and include those.  (To see if spikes of garbage being created/collected are the culprit.)  Otherwise, get a profiler and use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. Try running it alone without Eclipse and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

I experience this a lot it's not because of your libGdx project it's because of your computer. Computers just lag from time to time because of the multiple data or information they are handling everytime you're using it. Just ignore it man the important thing is you're making an awesome project, just don't mind the lag.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a dual monitor setup, can you ensure there's no GPU activity on the other display? I noticed even with a decent setup, if something else was on my opposite monitor (eg., a chat client or a browser window) projects would run at a significantly slower framerate.